# Substitute for siteedit taglib on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, was

I'm working on a project that has some JSP in it, with has some taglibs that don't work anymore, and I've searched far and wide, and can't find a replacement for it. Has anyone run into this problem? This was only used for some navbars.

The taglib in question is the following:

`<%@ taglib uri="http://www.ibm.com/siteedit/sitelib" prefix="siteedit" %>`

Comment: What is the taglib being used for? Is it even needed anymore?

Comment: It is being used as a prefix for navbars components, I'm trying to comment them to see if it works, but this is old code so I have no idea what was in that uri, since that site was moved. I was just dropped in this project blinded

Comment: Sounds like you're better off ripping it out and updating it 